# how to include template with context in navbar?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

In *base.html* I have included navbar `{% include 'partials/navbar.html' %}`, now I need to do *context* for *navbar.html*.

I trying to make context for *navbar.html* in this way:

*view.py*

```
def unread_conversation(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
       conversations_all = Conversation.objects.filter(Q(starter=request.user) |
                                                    Q(receiver=request.user))

       for conversation in conversations_all:
           unread = Message.objects.filter(Q(conversation_id=conversation.pk) &
                                        Q(seen=False) & ~Q(user=request.user))

       context = {
          'unread': unread
        }
       return render(request, 'conversations/unread_message.html', context)
    else:
       messages.error(request, 'register please')
       return redirect('register')
```

*unread_message.html*

```
{% if unread %}
  <span>You have new message</span>
{% endif %}
```

*navbar.html*

```
{% include 'conversations/unread_message.html' with unread=unread %}
```

but it does not work for me, can you correct my way or offer me a better way of this?

Comment: Have a look at this https://micropyramid.com/blog/inclusion-tags/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will solve this problem with this way:

I delete `unread_conversation()` from *view.py* and in this folder I create this structure:

```
  conversations/
      templatetags/
          __init__.py
          unreadmessage.py
```

in *unreadmessage.py*

```
from django import template # import this
from conversations.models import Conversation, Message
from django.db.models import Q
register = template.Library() # register this

@register.inclusion_tag('conversations/unread_message.html', takes_context=True)
def unread_conversation(context):
    request = context['request']
    conversations_all = Conversation.objects.filter(Q(starter=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user))
    if conversations_all.exists():
        for conversation in conversations_all:
            unread = Message.objects.filter(Q(conversation_id=conversation.pk) & Q(seen=False) & ~Q(user=request.user))
            return {'unread': unread}
```

in *unread_message.html*

```
{% if unread %}
    <span>You have new message</span>
{% endif %}
```

and the last step I load this tag in *navabar.html*

```
{% load unreadmessage %}
{% unread_conversation %} // function that created in unreadmessage.py
```

(thanks to @Biplove Lamichhane)